# Flutter web app with different Firebase projects

Tags: google-signin, firebase-hosting, flutter-web

I do have one Flutter web app, but because of our workflow we use multiple Firebase projects (dev, stage, prod) for hosting. This wouldn't be a big deal, if I don't need different index.html file.

Sadly we use Google SignIn and this will need a meta **google-signin-client_id** key. This differs between the projects.

What's the best practice to setup this project, so a CI/CD can deploy it without any changes to the index.html before upload? Is this even possible yet?

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: @user7856586 I added my current solution - it's not perfect, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My own solution, that I found somewhere:

- create flavor folders (eg. /web_flavors/dev and /web_flavors/prod)
- create a script, which copy the index.html from that flavor folders into /web before the compile

This way you will always have the right configuration within you build pipeline.

My only "problem" is, that I have to maintain the two files, if I need more HTML/JScript code in the index.html.

Comment: Could you share your script?

Comment: @JulioHenriqueBitencourt It's simple. I just created the folders and copy depending on my deployment target the folder into the /web folder, which is deployed into Firebase hosting.